# After freshly installing compass-inuit we get an error while starting up "compass watch"

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, inuit.css

We just created an compass project like described in the [compass-inuit manual](https://github.com/stephenway/compass-inuit).
When we now start "compass watch" we get the following error message:

```
user@VirtualXubuntu:/tmp/compass-test/my_project$ compass watch
>>> Change detected at 12:23:22 to: sass/style.scss
    error sass/sass/style.scss (Line 99: Invalid CSS after "}​": expected "{", was "")
identical stylesheets/sass/style.css 
>>> Compass is polling for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
```

Actually I don't know what this error means - since I'm a newbie in compass...

Version Info:

> Ubuntu 12.10 [amd64]
>   ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
>   Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam)

Comment: Looks like there is an error in your stylesheet around line 99 :) Maybe post your css code from around line 99

Comment: It's the plain style.scss I got from the compass setup routine:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/702aXDxb

Comment: Is it a problem because of the mixture of scss and sass? So compass created a scss file during setup and the compass compiler actually expects a sass file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in a newer version of the extension. Update by running `gem install compass-inuit -v 4.5.5.1`, then make a new project by running:

`compass create my_project -r compass-inuit --using compass-inuit`

I believe the cause of this error is one of the brackets isn't really a bracket but a pasted character. This causes the compiler to miss it and believe that a selector isn't closed.

Sorry for the hassle.